# Set search_path with file include in postgres psql command

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

How can I include multiple search paths in a psql command, so that multiple files can be run with different search_paths but all be run in one transaction?

```
psql
  --single-transaction
  --command="set search_path = 'a'; \i /sqlfile/a.sql; set search_path = 'b'; \i /sqlfile/b.sql;"
```

When I run this I get a syntax error at `\i`. I need to have the files included separately and they're generated dynamically so I'd rather run it using a `--command` than having to generate a file and using `--file` if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The manual about the `--command` option:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html)

> *`command`* must be either a command string that is completely parsable by
>   the server (i.e., it contains no psql-specific features), or a single
>   backslash command. Thus **you cannot mix SQL and psql meta-commands**
>   within a `-c` option. To achieve that, you could use repeated `-c` options
>   or pipe the string into psql [...]

Bold emphasis mine.

Try:

```
psql --single-transaction -c 'set search_path = a' -c '\i /sqlfile/a.sql' -c 'set search_path = b' -c '\i /sqlfile/b.sql'
```

Or use a *here-document*:

```
psql --single-transaction <<EOF
set search_path = a;
\i /sqlfile/a.sql
set search_path = b;
\i /sqlfile/b.sql
EOF
```

The `search_path` needs no quotes, btw.